# How to replace the mobile number with stars except last 4 digits in php

Tags: php, regex, replace

I am trying to replace the mobile number with stars except last 4 digits within a text and the text is dynamic.

```
Eg. John's Mobile number is 8767484343 and he is from usa.
Eg. John's Mobile number is +918767484343 and he is from india.
Eg. Sunny's Mobile number is 08767484343 and he is from india.
Eg. Rahul's Mobile number is 1800-190-2312 and he is from india.



$dynamic_var = "John's Mobile number is 8767484343 and he is from usa.";

$number_extracted = preg_match_all('!\d+!', $dynamic_var , $contact_number);

// don't know what to do next
```

> ```
> Result will be like 
> Eg. John's Mobile number is ******4343 and he is from usa.
> Eg. John's Mobile number is ******4343 and he is from india.
> Eg. Sunny's Mobile number is ******4343 and he is from india.
> Eg. Rahul's Mobile number is ******2312 and he is from india.
> ```

Comment: what are the rule for considering a number to be mobile number ? i.e we can have different kind of numbers mobile number, toll free numbers, landline numbers, etc.

Comment: a contact number can be anything with country code or without. and toll free numbers like 1800-120-9878 and if find any digit with + or - or without any of these it should replace the whole digit except last four.

Comment: well it is working but replacing last four digits to star. i Want to replace all the mobile numbers to star except last four digits to be as it is.

Comment: Ok, try `preg_replace_callback('~\+?\d+(?:[-\s]*\d)*(?=(?:[-\s]*\d){4}(?!-?\d))~', function($m) { return preg_replace('~\d~', '*', $m[0]); }, $dynamic_var)`

Comment: but it didn't relpaced + and - from other inputs

Comment: Then use `preg_replace('~[\d+-]~', '*', $m[0]);` inside.

Comment: You can only use ejuhjav's solution if the 4 digits at the end are always glued together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see of your sample input and your desired output, you don't need the overhead of `preg_replace_callback()`.  A variable length lookahead will allow you to replace one character at a time with an asterisk so long as it is followed by 4 or more digits or hyphens.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2hFF8))

```
$inputs = [
    "John's Mobile number is 8767484343 and he is from usa.",
    "John's Mobile number is +918767484343 and he is from india.",
    "Sunny's Mobile number is 08767484343 and he is from Pimpri-Chinchwad, india.",
    "Rahul's Mobile number is 1800-190-2312 and he is from india."
];

var_export(preg_replace('~[+\d-](?=[\d-]{4})~', '*', $inputs));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'John\'s Mobile number is ******4343 and he is from usa.',
  1 => 'John\'s Mobile number is *********4343 and he is from india.',
  2 => 'Sunny\'s Mobile number is *******4343 and he is from Pimpri-Chinchwad, india.',
  3 => 'Rahul\'s Mobile number is *********2312 and he is from india.',
)
```

I could dream up some fringe cases that will not be handled by my snippet, but whenever you are dealing with phone numbers that aren't obeying a strict format, you are going down a rabbit hole of challenges.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that directly from your $dynamic_var like this for example:

```
$dynamic_var = "John's Mobile number is 8767484343 and he is from usa.";
$result = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=\s)(\d|-|\+)+(?=\d{4}\s)/U', function($matches) {
    return str_repeat("*", strlen($matches[0]));
}, $dynamic_var);
```

Answer (score 1):

Old but useful...

```
<?php
    echo str_repeat('*', strlen("123456789") - 4) . substr("123456789", -4);
?>
```