# How can i replace a portion of string starting from the next 4 characters?

Tags: php

I have the below string:

```
$string = 005390326548;
```

How can i get this result?

```
0053****6548
```

Basically i want to replace starting from the 4 characters the next 4 characters by ****

Comment: We can't see your coding attempt / proof of research.  Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/q/56986004/2943403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one-liner solution.

```
$string= substr_replace("8487013103", "****", 4, 4);
echo $string;
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  Rushed answers make Stack Overflow worse.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '005390326548';
$retult = substr($string, 0, 4) . '****' . substr($string, 8);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  Rushed code-only answers make Stack Overflow worse.